# .net mvc submit error occurirng on one controller and not the other

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a solution that have 3 controllers. the views use a model view, a container for multiple lists and objects. when i tried submitting the model view in one of the controllers it works. a simple action paramtered as follow

```
[HttpPost]
[SubmitButtonClass(Name = "SubmitButtonName")]
public ActionResult SomeActionMethod(ModelView model, string some_string)
{
//do stuff here
}
```

now this format of action method is used in two controllers. but for some reason it doesn't work in one them saying there is no constructor defined. in my `routeconfig` i have multiple routes and there is one that takes one parameter. is there a reason why this works on a controller and not another?  one more thing i use a submit class to handle multiple submit buttons

```
public class SubmitButtonClass : ActionNameSelectorAttribute //used in case of multiple buttons
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public override bool IsValidName(ControllerContext controllerContext, string actionName, System.Reflection.MethodInfo methodInfo)
    {
        var value = controllerContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue(Name);

        if (value == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error message your getting?

Comment: System.MissingMethodException. i tried rebuilding/cleaning/building the solution but in vain

Comment: Edit your question with the details. And what is the difference between the methods that work and the one that does not.

Comment: well there is no difference that's the problem. same params and when i debugged i figured out that the method when submitting is not even reached. even thought the buttons have the same. called properly.

Answer (score 0):

I found out i was looking at the wrong place. it had nothing to do with my controller. i had in my view a hidden html helper that takes the value of a property like this `@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.importDefinition.Item1.code)`. that caused the error and it's technically this the actual error `No parameterless constructor defined for this object.`